# Автообновление содержимых блоков

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

И снова, это обновление :) Понимаю на просторах интернета полно таких скриптов, но не один не подходит для меня. У всех скриптов, которых я встречал я видел, что у всех только 1 блок <div> обновляется, а мне требуется что бы одним файлом(где будет PHP) в 3 разные <div> выводило 3 разных значения. Снизу привел простой пример, можно ли его как нибудь доработать ?

```
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#div').fadeOut('slow').load('actions/stats.php').fadeIn("slow");

        }, 5000);
```

P.S: Не беспокойтесь за то что нагрузка будет большая, у меня это обновление в админке. Обновляется статистика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация зависит от того, как у вас формируются данные в обработчике. По идее, для каждого из блоков вывода, у вас должны генерироваться свои данные. В этом случае, их лучше "упаковывать" в массив, где ключами, к примеру, могут быть ID или классы блоков вывода и содержать соответствующие значения статистики и отправлять ответом всё это дело преобразовав в формат json. Для простого примера, сделайте два файла и запишите туда следующее:

**demo.html** (вывод данных)

```
// JS/jQuery
$(function(){
    var cnt = 0,
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'stat.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {some_params: 1},
            success:function(data){
                for(var key in data){
                    $('.'+key).text(data[key]);
                }
            }
        });
        if(cnt++ > 10) clearInterval(timer);
    }, 2000);
});
// в тело - три блока
<div class="stat1"></div>
<div class="stat2"></div>
<div class="stat3"></div>
```

**stat.php** (обработчик)

```
<?php
function getRandInt(){
    return rand(1, 100);
}
$response = array(
    'stat1'=>'Num1: '.getRandInt(),
    'stat2'=>'Num2: '.getRandInt(),
    'stat3'=>'Num3: '.getRandInt(),
);
exit( json_encode($response) );
```

Файлы в одной директории. Запустите первый и понаблюдайте.

P.S.

> Не беспокойтесь за то что нагрузка будет большая...

А мы и не беспокоимся ツ Это ваша головная боль. В админке или нет, а нагрузка всё равно на сервер в целом идёт.